# Not able to upgrade vmware tools on esxi 6.0 running as vm in vcenter

Tags: esxi, vcenter

Try updating vmware tools of esxi(6.0) OS running in vm in vcenter. 
Getting error like Operation Failed, vmware tools iso does not exists or not accessible.
try mounting the esxi iso on vm, but mount command not found in Esxi.

Comment: Have you tried to download the appropriate version of the [ISO](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/573113)?

Comment: You may also want to update ESXi to the most current version ([6.7u3](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/evalcenter?p=free-esxi6)), as 6.0 is >4yrs old.

Comment: @JW0914 - 6.7u3 might not be supported by the authors question.  I know any version beyond 6.5 isn’t supported by mine.

Comment: @Ramhound https://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/6.0/index.html i navigate to this link to choose iso for ESXi 6.0 but i found its asking me to choose ubuntu, sles, windows what i need to choose for ESXi Any idea ??

Comment: You install the tools within the OS running on the VM.  It’s not clear what your trying to do.  I have extensive knowledge of vCenter and ESXi

Comment: actually i have make nested setup of esxi, means i have a vcenter having esxi hosts connected, i create a vm install esxi in that, there its asking to upgrade vmware tools. that i am not able to do. hope you understand now @Ramhound

Comment: You install the tools through vCenter to the guest OS, but you still use the ISO, and it’s still on the VM not ESXi.